# Configure Angular DataTable Renderer with TypeScript instead of JavaScript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-datatables

I'm setting up [Angular DataTables](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/getting-started) with the Responsive plugin in my Angular app for the first time and it's not clear how to configure the Renderer using TypeScript.  [The example given](https://datatables.net/reference/option/responsive.details.renderer) is in JavaScript.  I have created a template reference variable and called the DataTable function on it, but it gives an error that 'DataTable' doesn't exist on type 'ElementRef >any>'

```
    this.dataTableID.DataTable({
      responsive: {
        details: {
          renderer: $.fn.dataTable.Responsive.renderer.tableAll()
        }
      }  
    })
```

I also tried passing the renderer function as part of the dtOptions, but I get this build error: "Property 'Responsive' does not exist on type 'StaticFunctions'".

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dtOptions = {
      responsive: {
        details: {
          renderer: $.fn.dataTable.Responsive.renderer.tableAll()
        }
      }
    };
  }
```

How do I convert this example to TypeScript for Angular?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this, from then datatables examples?
https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/extensions/responsive

just the " responsive: true " bit is important...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the data table of angular material https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview